# Dynamic element added to the object JSDOC

Tags: javascript, object, jsdoc, javascript-intellisense

**I am using the Visual Studio 2017**

I  have the object which have the lots of properties added to it inside constructor. Some are strings and some are objects. The "**O**" object have the auto intellisense on it.

But the problem is that if I add the property out of the constructor to **"O"** object i.e

`O.SampleProperty = "string";`

Then it did not have the intellisense on it.

**How I can add intellsense of "SampleProperty" property to object?**

Also I don't want to disturb the auto generated intellisense of the "**O**" object because I have added lot's of nested objects inside that object constructor and I don't want to write the jsdoc for each nested object because it is auto generated.

```
let O = {

PropertyA: "Testing",

PropertyB: {Testing: "A"}

};

// The above object have auto intellisense which contains the both properties.

// Now I am trying to add the property out of the constructor
O.SampleProperty = "testing";

// Now the O object did not have the "SampleProperty" in intellisense.
```

Comment: Well what IDE is it??

Comment: I am using the Visual Studio 2017 Community edition

Comment: Any one who can help me on this?